# useing exec with parameters c

Tags: c, exec

I made a program that gets a path for directory compiles the files in that directory's folders and executes them.

Now I tried using `execl` but I don't really know what the name of the executed files will be before I run the program.

Because the name of the file is the name of the folder it is in.
(for example I have `.../omer/omer.c` and I compile it to omer)
now when I execute I want to do something like that for it to work properly:

```
execl("./omer","./omer",NULL);
```

the way I was trying to do it is (I have the filename):

```
execl("./%s",fileName,"./%s",fileName);
```

but that doesn't do anything. Now the problem is that I can't use `strcat()` so I'm trying to avoid creating a function to create a string that has the "./" at the beginning ..

Is there any way to do what I tried without using something like `strcat()` or there's no way to avoid it
(basically I want to insert custom string to the `execl`)?

Thanks for helping!

edit : 
adding more of the code as requested :

```
cFilePath = 
readStudentcFilePath(confContent[0],studentName,strLeng(confContent[0]));
pid = fork();
if(pid<0)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Forking Error!\n");
  exit(FORK_ERR);
}
if(pid == 0)
{
  execl("/usr/bin/gcc","gcc",cFilePath,"-o",studentName,NULL);
  fprintf(stderr, "Failed to Execute file 'gcc' \n");
  exit(EXEC_ERR);
}
pid = fork();
if(pid<0)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Forking Error!\n");
  exit(FORK_ERR);
}
if(pid == 0)
{
  studentOutFd = open("test_output.txt",O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT);
  if(studentOutFd < 0 )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error Opening File 'test_output.txt'\n");
    exit(FILE_OPEN_ERR);
  }
  dup2(STDIN_FILENO,inFd);
  dup2(STDOUT_FILENO,studentOutFd);
  execl("./%s",studentName,"./%s",studentName,NULL);
  fprintf(stderr, "Error Executing File %s\n", studentName);
  exit(EXEC_ERR);
}
```

Comment: You don't need strcat to build a string. Just do it yourself.

Comment: ofc i can build the string myself , as i said I'm trying to avoid doing it... I don't want to build a string every time so i wonder if there're any way to do what i need without building a new one ..
if there isn't ill just build a string ... but that's the easy (and long) way ..

Comment: That's the only way.

Comment: Probably a bigger portion of your code would elp to understand better the relationship between the program's arguments and exec's argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to prepend `"./"` to the name of the file if you are using `execl` (or any `exec` variant which doesn't have a `p` in its name). All of these versions of `exec` interpret their first argument as a pathname in the usual way; that is, as an absolute path if it starts with a `/` and as path relative to the current working directory otherwise.

The `exec` variants which do have a `p` in their name (`execlp`, `execvp`, etc.) interpret their first argument differently if it does not contain a `/`. In this case, the pathname is searched for in the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable (or a library-specific default, usually `/usr:/usr/bin`). Since `.` is not generally included in `PATH`, the filename will not be searched for in the current working directory.

Since the shell you use duplicates the functioning of `execlp`, you cannot run executables in the current working directory by just specifying their filename. You must write `./omer` instead of `omer`. (Unless you add `.` to your `PATH`, of course. This is not recommended for security reasons.) Since `./omer` includes a slash, it does not incur the `PATH` search.

But that doesn't apply to `execl`, so it is not necessary to include a `/` in order to force the use as a relative path.

If you did feel the need to specify a particular directory (such as `/usr/share/lib/myapp`), then you would need to concatenate a filepath. In that case, if you cannot use `strcat` (or don't want to use it), then you would have to write your own concatenation function. The `%s` expansion is not a language syntax. It's part of the `printf` and related library functions. (One of those related functions is `snprintf`, which is usually a safer and more convenient way of creating a string at runtime than repeated calls to `strcat`. However, if `strcat` is not available to you, it seems unlikely that `snprintf` is.)

Comment: Ok so I guess I didn't understand the use of execl properly but that clarified a lot.
Thanks!